# impact of Meltdown/Spectre patches?

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan

Has anyone timed the impact of the Spectre/Meltdown patches for OS X or macOS?

I just updated my El Capitan based Mac Pro (#1), and noticed a 6% slowdown (#2) on my major benchmark (compiling 500 C files (about 1/2 million lines) from the Terminal).

The update is the "Security Update 2018-001", which addresses Meltdown and Spectre according to https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208465

Stan

1. early 2009, 16 cores, 20 GB RAM
2. Tests repeated 3 times, files brought into memory first, best of the three tests compared showing 6% slowdown.  If average of times used instead, still shows 6%.  No other "apps" running.

Comment: I would be interested to hear answers to this question, but I think it is probably going to be closed for being off topic or too broad, or not being clear what is asked... or whatever... so If you do find a way to collect some data I would love to see it

Comment: Grady says: "I would love to see it" ... all I have available now is the results of "time make".  I did a "make clean", a "make", then a "make clean" again.  That meant that all the source files were in memory.  
Then I did three "time make ; make clean"s.  
Before:
real 0m9.488s
user 1m21.268s
sys 0m36.375s

real 0m9.213s
user 1m21.271s
sys 0m35.850s

real 0m9.421s
user 1m21.489s
sys 0m36.186s

----------------

after patches

real 0m9.956s
user 1m26.134s
sys 0m35.511s

real 0m9.792s
user 1m26.119s
sys 0m35.743s

real 0m9.770s
user 1m26.487s
sys 0m35.915s

Comment: sorry for messy comment above.  comment text seems to lack any formatting abilities, and is limited in size.  Short version: no more tests possible, since the patch is now installed.